Why do we have money growth in the medium to long run?
Over the long run, why do we have money growth and inflation? There's two explanations I had in mind, wanted to know which one, if either, is correct

If we have expected inflation at 2%, then next year prices and wages go up by two percent since this is written into contracts and firms expect it as well so they raise prices. This would cause the LM curve to shift upwards since the real money supply has gone down. In order to keep the economy in general equilibrium or so there isn't a temporary recession, the central bank increases money supply from year to year

Potential output or the FE line shifts to the right over time as the economy grows, and to prevent price levels from falling, and to keep interest rates stable, the central bank keeps on increasing the money supply and overshoots


If possible, could someone refer me to an article or perhaps a chapter in some textbook that covers inflation and money growth well, at an introductory level within the context of the IS-LM or AD-AS model. I didn't enjoy the way my textbook covered the topic and I'm kind of confused about this.
